# Issue Deploying Raiden Contracts and Starting Raiden Client on Private Geth Network

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, geth

I am trying to deploy Raiden smart contracts and start Raiden client on a private GETH network using [this](https://github.com/raiden-network/raiden/blob/master/docs/private_net_tutorial.rst) tutorial from the Raiden team but it seems to be outdated and I am running into multiple errors, so I am able to deploy all the Raiden contracts with contract-version==0.25.0 successfully on GETH v1.9.21-stable but starting up Raiden client v0.200.0-rc9-macOS-x86_64 I get this error

`[UserDeposit] Address 0x246c6c859B0ab7ab970cA2f3764B757c20CD5477 has wrong code. This may happen if Raiden is configured to use an unsupported version of the contracts.`

It is the same error when I try with Raiden client v1.x.x. I decided to take another look at deploying Raiden contracts with contract-version==0.37.0 after failing to deploy on GETH v1.10.1-stable, reaching out to the dev team and they suggested using v1.9.21-stable, but I get a vague error. which is hard to debug when deploying the **TokenNetworkRegistry.sol**

`raise ValueError("Status 0 indicates failure")`

Printing out web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txhash) for **TokenNetworkRegistry.sol** the status is indeed 0 and it throws an **Out of Gas** exception. Increasing the gas limit still throws the same exception.

Comment: Because the pool of developers that know Raiden this well is limited to their internal team, it makes sense to ask the question from Raiden developers directly.

Comment: Yes, thank you @MikkoOhtamaa I have created a corresponding GitHub issue